# How to find complexity of algorithm from running times given

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I have three algorithms namely A,B,C. Below is the size of input and their respective running times.

```
Size of Input     A    B   C    
----------------------------             

         512     70  135  42

        1024    134  517  86

        2048    262 2053 182
```

In those three algorithms, one has O(n) and one has O(nlogn) and another has O(n^2)...

Comment: Yeah, I tried, but I got a doubt that I have taken size of input in x axis and running time in y axis. I have taken x as 512 units and y as 70 units... I got doubt that can I take different units. I forgotten my school mathematics sadly...

Comment: Just look at the input size and the respective execution times. When you double the input size, what happens to the execution time? Does it double, as well? Is it slightly more than double? Does it quadruple?

Comment: Yeah I tried that also but A and C are approximately leading to O(n).. and B is O(nlogn) but there is no O(n^2)

Answer (score 1):

The different complexity levels can be understood, very roughly, like this:

- O(1): When you change the input size, the time takes does not change at all.
- O(log n): When you double the input size, the time taken increases by some constant amount.
- O(n): When you double the input size, the time taken is doubled, too.
- O(n log n): When you double the input size, the time taken is a bit more than doubled.
- O(n<sup>2</sup>): When you double the input size, the time taken is four times as much.
- O(2<sup>n</sup>): When you increase the input by some constant amount, the time taken is doubled.

With this, you can eyeball the solution from the few values that are provided. Note that the input size is always doubled. In which case in the time taken about doubled, too? When is it a bit more than that? When is it quadrupled?

Finally, you can try to find linear or quadratic functions that produce (roughly) those results (i.e. running times) for the given inputs. If you can find a linear equation (in the form *y=ax+b*) then it's O(n), if you need a quadratic, then it's O(n<sup>2</sup>), and so on.

Comment: O(log n): If the input size doubles the runtime increases by one

Answer (score 0):

In reality big-O notation is poor at defining how a functions grows between two specific input sizes. Several problems have O(exp n) but in reality run better than some non exponential functions.

The omited constants can be so large as to render the problem unworkable even though the algorithm may have a moderately low complexity.

I suspect this is a homework problem, in which case, look how each function grows, does it increase linearly with the input size, for example.